# I am getting 0.0 while trying to load pdf using react-native-pdf

Tags: react-native-pdf

I have installed the latest version, its depndencies following their doc but i am only getting 0.0

I was expecting to see a pdf rendered. I have tried installing many times but I am getting the same result. I even tried creating a whole new project but still get the same result